How can I query FHIR server to return all panel tests and independent tests in one go
I have a patient portal that connects to an FHIR server to get patient's lab tests.
I want to get all the panel/grouped tests and individual tests in one query. Is there a way to do that?

If you query for Observations, the default is that you'll get all Observations - both panels and leaf-level Observations.  It's actually really hard (and not widely supported) to query in a way that doesn't give you both.
Simply search filtering where ?category=laboratory&patient=[your patient]

Thanks @Lloyd
Can you tell me how can I show only the observations which are panels or the observations that are leaf-levelled but not connected to any panel?

You can try ?has-member:missing=false to find panels.  You could try ?_has:Observation:has-member:patient=123 where patient 1234 is the same patient as the patient you're looking for.  (With _has, you need to search on some property of the referencing resource.)  Whether your server will actually support these may vary.
